Microsoft Teams integration with AzureDevops Boards to create Workitems on demand
We are using azuredevops service and server 2022. Since we are planning to use azuredevops work items as a way to manage our Devops support request from developers, we were looking for an automated solution from MS teams, so that as Devops engineer, we can predefine different work item template with the required fields for each category of request(eg: some may be access request, Resource provisioning request, delete request, or some network change request etc..).. So the developers can easily access and prefill the required templates with all the related fields of their selected category and submit the work item to our azuredevops.
So far, we tried till here, but not getting a way to achieve the work item creation scenario in a processed way as we expected above.

Installed the "Azure DevOps" app for Microsoft Teams:
Added to a team"
Connected the app to  Azure DevOps organization, teams dashboard

But from here, we couldn't achieve the scenario

You are almost there. Please refer the following steps to achieve the work item creation scenario.

First, capture work items as templates to predefine different work item templates with the required fields for each category of request. By saving the templates and selecting Copy link, you can get the URLs for the templates.
Create a team dashboard in your Azure DevOps service project.
Add the Markdown widget to the dashboard and configure the widget with your template links.


Sample Markdown content
### Templates to create workitems

- [access request](https://dev.azure.com/xxx/testproject/_workitems/create/Issue?templateId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&ownerId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)
- [Resource provisioning request](https://dev.azure.com/xxx/testproject/_workitems/create/Issue?templateId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&ownerId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)
- [delete request](https://dev.azure.com/xxx/testproject/_workitems/create/Issue?templateId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&ownerId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)
- [network change request](https://dev.azure.com/xxx/testproject/_workitems/create/Issue?templateId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&ownerId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)


Install the "Azure DevOps" app for Microsoft Teams and add it to a team. Then connect the app to the team's dashboard where you added the Markdown widget.

Now, you can see the templates of the work items in the dashboard from the Teams channel tap. Your developers can click the links to go to the work item create page with predefine fields.




Great.. Will this work for azuredevops server instance as well ?

Hi @Vowneee, when I tested the Azure DevOps app in Teams, it shows: You must first select an existing Azure DevOps Services organization. So, this app can only be used for Azure DevOps Services organization, not Azure DevOps Server.  As a workaround, you can also write the work item templates from Azure DevOps Server in the Azure DevOps Services dashboard. Then they can see the template links to create work item for Azure DevOps Server. Sample

Wow.. Seems this will be an nice workaround. will test this .. I accepted this answer
